# drawLayer:inContext - Unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to create a UIViewController that draws a layer and it works fine if this UIViewController is the main one. However, if I try to initialize it inside another controller and then add it's view as a sub view of the main controller's view it results in the following error:

```
-[__NSCFType drawLayer:inContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155140
```

Here is the relevant code for my custom UIViewController (PDFPageViewController):

```
- (void)loadDocument:(PDFDocument *)document
{
    self._document = document;

    CGRect pageRect = CGRectIntegral(CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(self._document.page, kCGPDFCropBox));

    pageRect.origin.x = (self.view.frame.size.width / 2) - (pageRect.size.width / 2) - 35;

    CATiledLayer *tiledLayer = [CATiledLayer layer];
    tiledLayer.delegate = self;
    tiledLayer.tileSize = CGSizeMake(1024.0, 1024.0);
    tiledLayer.levelsOfDetail = 1000;
    tiledLayer.levelsOfDetailBias = 1000;
    tiledLayer.frame = pageRect;

    contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:pageRect];
    [contentView.layer addSublayer:tiledLayer];

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin = CGPointZero;

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.contentSize = pageRect.size;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1000;
    [scrollView addSubview:contentView];

    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];   

    NSLog(@"%@", self); // Just checking if there's nothing overwriting the layer's delegate
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return contentView;
}

- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    if(self._document) {
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(ctx));
        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, layer.bounds.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(self._document.page, kCGPDFCropBox, layer.bounds, 0, true));
        CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, self._document.page);
    }
}
```

The *drawLayer* method is there and the *CALayer*'s delegate is *self*.

And this is how I call it on my main controller:

```
pageViewController = [[[PDFPageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:NULL bundle:NULL] autorelease];
[pageViewController loadDocument:self.document];

[self.view addSubview:[pageViewController view]];
```

Am I not doing this the proper way? I can't understand why this works fine if I draw the layer on my main controller and it results on an error if the draw is made on PDFViewController. The method is in there, the delegate is *self*. So why is the selector failing?

Comment: This sounds like a memory management problem. Have you tried NSZombieEnabled? Is there any chance you've over-released something? Are you using ARC?

Comment: @jbandes - Thank you so much! With NSZombieEnabled I saw just as you said that the message was been sent to a deallocated instance of my view controller and then I proceded to fix the over-releasing. Please post an answer to this question so I can mark it and you can take the bounty.

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help! I think you have to separately assign the bounty, just marking it as the answer doesn't assign it.

Comment: I have to wait 19 hours to assign the bounty (I placed the bounty today) tomorrow I'll assign it to you. Again thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Re-posted from the comments because it turned out to be the answer!]

This sounds like a memory management problem. Have you tried NSZombieEnabled? Is there any chance you've over-released something? Are you using ARC?